# Subscribing to Angular2 eventEmitter not receiving value

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have multiple functions all with a different signature:

```
getBooks(author, id);
getMusic(year, genre);
getProduct(name, id);
```

All returning the same type of data: `pagedData`. This pagedData contains the data itself and nextUrl to fetch the next page:

```
{
   data: [
     ...
   ]
   nextUrl: "http://api.com?page2"
}
```

In Angular2 I've created a pagedData component which I want to reuse. For books, music and product the page looks the same. The only difference is the html inside the for loop which iterates over all items.

The code for the component looks like:

```
export class PagedData implements OnInit {

    @Output() loadMore = new EventEmitter();

    nextPage = null;

    pageData: IPagedData;

    constructor() {
        this.loadMore.subscribe(res => {
            console.log('res', res);
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadMore.emit();
    }

}
```

And the Book specific code like:

```
@Component({
    template: `
        <paged-data (loadMore)="update($event)"></paged-data>
    `
})

export class BooksPage {

    constructor(
        public bookService: BookService) {
    }

    update(event) {
        return this.BookService.getBooks('jack', 29349);
    }

}
```

My problem is that even I've subscribed to the `loadMore` and emit the event, the `console.log('res', res);` keeps showing `res, undefined`.

Does anyone see what is going wrong? In the old days I would have made a callback instead of an emitter and just let every page give another callback to the component. The component then could call that function to fetch the data. Maybe I am thinking to wrong way to create such behaviour with an event emitter.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.loadMore.emit();
```

doesn't emit a value.
If you use

```
this.loadMore.emit('foo');
```

you'll get a different output

Comment: I see, what I don't get is that the constructor of my component doesn't seem to subscribe to the observable of `this.BookService.getBooks('jack', 29349)`. What I basically want is to give an arbitrary method to my component which is used to fetch the data and shows it in the component. This could be any function but always returns IPageData

Comment: It's not obvious from your code what you expect to happen. What does `getBooks(...)` do? What does it return, or are you even trying to use the return value?

Comment: getBooks returns an Observable and I am trying to use the return value of this observable to show in my component.

Comment: What I want to achieve is to give my Component an arbitrary Observable and display the return value of that observable in the template of the component.

Comment: `(loadMore)="update($event)"` is the only place in your code where you call `this.BookService.getBooks(...)` and this way the return value is just ignored.

Comment: You would need something like `<div>{{(update() | async)?.someProp}}</div>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143436/discussion-between-osi-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Answer (score 1):

Output variables are used for emmiting and not use them observables

```
@Output() loadMore = new EventEmitter<string>();

this.loadMore.emit(..);
```

It should also have a type of `<T>`

Comment: Technically you can subscribe to them, although perhaps you shouldn't because the capability may be removed. Good advice about the types though.